# Flexbox: how to get divs to fill up 100% of the container width without wrapping?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm in the process of updating an old `inline-block`-based grid model I have to a newer Flexbox one I created. Everything has worked fine, apart from one little snag, which has become a bit of a dealbreaker:

I have a bunch of CSS-controlled sliders; so there's a containing wrapper with 100% width, and inside is another div: its width is also 100%, but its `white-space` is set to `nowrap`. Using `inline-block`, this meant that the internal divs (which were *also* set to 100% width) wouldn't be bound by their parents' constraints and wrap onto the next line - they'd just carry on flowing out of the box. This is exactly what I wanted. However, I cannot get this to work at all with flexbox. For reference, here's an image:

[image: Flexbox problem]

And for reference, here's a jsFiddle of the thing working with inline-block: http://jsfiddle.net/5zzvqx4b/

...and *not* working with Flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/5zzvqx4b/1/

I've tried all kinds of variations with `flex`, `flex-basis`, `flex-wrap`, `flex-grow`, etc. but for the life of me I can't get this to work.

Note that I *can* force it to do what I want in a hacky, inflexible way by setting the `.boxcontainer` width to `200%`. That works for this single example, but in some cases I won't know beforehand how many child boxes there will be, and I'd rather not resort to inline styling on each element if possible.

Comment: ... not an answer, but why do you want to change flex, you have a working code already which is prefix free, and will work on more browsers?

Comment: @sdcr: Because of the other requirements of the project which, at ~20,000 lines of code, would probably take a little while to go into.

Comment: oh, ok just to say that some of the flex properties you set there aren't even necessary, such as `flex-direction: row;`, `justify-content: flex-start;`, `align-items: flex-start;` those are default rules, unless you're overwriting them. there is a great guide [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: @sdcr: Thanks - it is indeed very verbose in that example, but only because I copy-n-pasted it directly from my stylesheet, in which there are a lot of conditions and subclasses, etc. which is why the properties are set explicitly. I don't know flexbox well enough to write it off the top of my head yet!

Comment: makes senses then, be aware, browser support for flex is IE10+ with the -ms* prefix.

Comment: Great question! Been wondering about this forever myself. Never knew how the `flex-shrink` property worked.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

To prevent the flex items from shrinking, set the [flex shrink factor](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-shrink-factor) to `0`:

> The **flex shrink factor** determines how much the [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) will
>   shrink relative to the rest of the [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) in the flex
>   container when negative free space is distributed. When omitted, it is
>   set to 1.

```css
.boxcontainer .box {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.boxcontainer {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid #BDC3C7;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  display: flex;
}
.boxcontainer .box {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.boxcontainer .box:first-child {
  background-color: #F47983;
}
.boxcontainer .box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #FABCC1;
}
#slidetrigger:checked ~ .wrapper .boxcontainer {
  left: -100%;
}
#overflowtrigger:checked ~ .wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="overflowtrigger" />
<label for="overflowtrigger">Hide overflow</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="slidetrigger" />
<label for="slidetrigger">Slide!</label>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="boxcontainer">
    <div class="box">
      First bunch of content.
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Second load  of content.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 86):

You can use the shorthand flex property and set it to

```
flex: 0 0 100%;
```

That's `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis` in one line. Flex shrink was described above, flex grow is the opposite, and flex basis is the size of the container.

Answer (score 57):

In my case, just using `flex-shrink: 0` didn't work. But adding `flex-grow: 1` to it worked.

```css
.item {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Set the `flex-direction: column`

You're trying to stack the items in a column rather than a row.

```
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

addition thing - size of flex wrapper (need for background width/height and context size of block), for this we can use display:inline-flex;