# why here i am not getting scroll event , but click event is firing may be something i am doing wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, onscroll

So here  is the code and I want to get the scroll event object on the scroll of div which content is a lot so div becomes scrollable how we can get scroll event and why its not working

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
  return (
    <div onScroll={(e) => console.log(e)}>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, facilis
      magni d.......
      ...............
      vero!
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You'll need to share more information and create a [mre]. I can't reproduce the issue you're having: https://jsfiddle.net/d89qs3ot/ (tested with React 17)

Comment: You need to add fixed height to the div and add overflow auto or scroll

Comment: Try this to scroll events in the right way. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61018017/19165856

Comment: @NickParsons here i reproduce the issue https://jsfiddle.net/c8gdrby9/

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you want to make the element itself scrollable or just want the app to console.log the object whenever you scroll the page....

but if you want to console.log the object anyway try to attach an event listener to the document like this ...

note that you need to get the `getBoundingClientRect()` to know if the screen is on the element you want

```js
function scroll() {
const element = document.querySelector("div")
const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
if( rect.top <= 200 )//any number above 100 will work
       {console.log("scrolled")}
}
document.addEventListener('scroll', scroll);
```

this way whenever you scroll the window over the element, the scroll function will work
hope it helps you

Comment: its not working i used it in the useEffect with empty dependency but not get scroll event

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're not scrolling your div that you have `onScroll` on (from your link in the comments, that is the `pagesContainer` div), but rather, are scrolling your entire body. It's easier to see if you add another element below your `onScroll` div as you'll see that content shift as you scroll. In the reproducible example you shared, your `.pagesContainer` div is 500vw, so you need to scroll the container of that div (ie: the body) to see the contents. Instead, you want to keep `.pagesContainer` the width of your screen (ie: `100vw`) but make each page (`.pages`) within the container of your div span `100%` of that width (this can be done by using `flex: 0 0 100%;`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687608/5648954)). This way, you will have elements within your `pagesContainer` div "overflowing" its width. You need to ensure that you add `overflow-x: scroll;` to the parent to specify that it should add a scrollbar when the content overflows rather than render it outside of the container.

See example below (view browser console for logs):

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="pagesContainer" onScroll={(e) => console.log("scroll")}>
      <div className="pages">page1</div>
      <div className="pages">page2</div>
      <div className="pages">page3</div>
      <div className="pages">page4</div>
      <div className="pages">page5</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* just to remove whitespace padding */
}
.pagesContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw; /* change to 100vw*/
  overflow-x: scroll; /* important to specify scrolling behaviour when the content overflows */
}

.pages {
  flex: 0 0 100%; /* make each page 100% of the container */
  height: 100vh;
}
.pages:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(225, 143, 143);
}
.pages:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(130, 130, 215);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```