# P tag word wrapping

Tags: html

For illustration purposes I will make this simple.  I have the following p tag

```
<p>Test Store - (Test Location)</p>
```

Now when I make the width of the browser smaller it starts to wrap the text so the text comes something like this

```
Test Store 
 - 

(Test Location)
```

This is not what I want, I want to avoid wrapping the text and treat the whole thing as one block, so when the browser width becomes small I want it to move the whole text down instead of just part of the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a DIV not wrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718891/how-to-make-a-div-not-wrap)

Comment: You can also use non-breaking spaces in the test `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1):

Use the Css `p{white-space:nowrap;}`