# Html Hyphen (-) New Line Copy Paste Error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developping a MVC project and facing a weird problem.

In my view;

If I define a div like this

```
  <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding-top: 10px">05931-1</div>
```

[image]

Hyphen is displayed in a new line. (second textbox)

When I Copy-paste this text into the text box and submit the form,
everything is fine. I make a web service call and I get the proper results.

[image]

When I define the div like this, hyphen is not shown in new line.

```
<div class="col-lg-1" style="padding-top: 10px">05931&#8209;1</div>
```

[image]

When I copy paste this result and debug the code I can also see the same values for the input however, web service returns empty results as if there is a problem.

[image]

Any idea about this behavior?

Comment: That's just standard wrapping behaviour because the content is bigger than the area. You can force it to not wrap by making the container bigger or using CSS [like this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718891/how-to-make-a-div-not-wrap)

Comment: but when I debug, input.CimIstasyon is same in both cases

Comment: a hypen like in your text equates to &#45; not #8209; they arent comparible texts .. 8209 specifically is NON line breaking..

Comment: @Zbidi: Just cause they look the same, does not mean they are the same character

Comment: <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding-top: 10px">05931&#45;1</div>        this  also does not show in the same line

Comment: @musefan do you mean the debugger shows the same results, but actually are they not the same results?

Comment: @Zbidi so you're getting the results as expected...

Comment: Thanks guys, I got the point. Thank you very much for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short

a hypen like in your text equates to - not #8209; they arent comparible texts .. 8209 specifically is NON line breaking, eg, do not wrap the line here

You are getting expected results.

Comment: Thanks BugFinder.