# Have an overflow-x of overflow-y elements

Tags: html, css, overflow

Here is a code snippet:

```css
div.one {
  width: 98%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
div.two {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 3px dotted orange;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class='one'>
    <div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div><div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div><div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div><div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div><div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div><div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the `div.one` have a horizontal scroll bar? I want the text to be exactly how it is with that vertical scroll bar. I want all the boxes on the same line and be able to scroll through them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a DIV not wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718891/how-to-make-a-div-not-wrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17005139/4120196) post.

I added

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: auto;
```

to `div.one`

and

```
display: inline-block; 
white-space: normal;
```

to `div.two`, removing `float:left;`

```css
div.one {
  width: 98%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
div.two {
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px dotted orange;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class='one'>
    <div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div><div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div><div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div><div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div><div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div><div class='two'>
    <p>
    Hasdaoidhaidhadauahsduahsduyaudagduygaukdyagduakiysdgasudagdkuaysd
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```