# Jekyll generate html code with newline problem

Tags: html, jekyll

I use jekyll to generate my blog, and there is the code:

```
##  Skills

### **Familiar with**
<img align="left" alt="python" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/python.png" />
<img align="left" alt="anaconda" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/anaconda.png" />
<img align="left" alt="bash" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/bash.png" />
<img align="left" alt="numpy" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/numpy.png" />
<img align="left" alt="pytorch" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/pytorch.png" />
<img align="left" alt="git" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/git.png" />
<img align="left" alt="c" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/c.webp" />
<img align="left" alt="github" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/github.svg" />
<img align="left" alt="vscode" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/vscode.png" />
<br>


### **Knowing**
<img align="left" alt="pycharm" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/pycharm.png" />
<img align="left" alt="vim" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/vim.png" />
<img align="left" alt="pandas" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/pandas.png" />
<img align="left" alt="matlab" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/matlab.png" />
<img align="left" alt="blogdown" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/blogdown.png" />
<img align="left" alt="RStudio" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/rstudio.png" />
<img align="left" alt="R" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/r.png" />
<img align="left" alt="opencv" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/opencv.png" />
<img align="left" alt="cmake" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/cmake.webp" />
<img align="left" alt="linux" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/linux.png" />
<img align="left" alt="Ubuntu" height="35px" style="margin:0px 4px" src="/assets/img/skills/ubuntu.png" /> 
<br>
```

The result will be good in my PC view like that:
[image]

But it don't work well in mobile view, like that:

[image]

I want the view that after the last icon there will be a newline.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot

Comment: What, exactly, _should_ it look like on mobile?  It seems to be wrapping to fit in the narrower window just fine.

Comment: @RyanM Yeah, right, I want to make it wrap to fit well. After the last icon and then newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a css question, not a jekyll or html question, perhaps you'd have best luck tagging css. To answer your question, try wrapping your sets of images around a div such as:

```
<div style="display: flex; white-space:nowrap; overflow:auto; ">
<img...
<img...
</div>
```

Reference: [How to make a DIV not wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718891/how-to-make-a-div-not-wrap)

Of course the best course of action would be to specify a class to the div tag and put the style in your CSS file.

Comment: Yes, this is a css question, . Thanks, this is very helpful.